# Windows RT 8.1 Sharpdevelop Issue (MSB3644) (MSB3248)

Tags: windows, desktop, sharpdevelop

I've signed the Windows RT Desktop version of Sharpdevelop, but I continuously get [this error](http://pastebin.com/i51GCPje)

```
Build started.
Warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
Error MSB3248: Parameter "SearchPaths" has invalid value "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}%3b
      %3b
      {HintPathFromItem}%3b
      {TargetFrameworkDirectory}%3b
      {Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}%3b
      %3b
      {GAC}%3b
      {RawFileName}%3b
      bin\Release\System.winmd". Illegal characters in path.
Build failed. (00:00:01.5781253)
```

All I need to do is get the exe compiled. I can sign it separately.

Comment: This is Sharpdevelop 3.2 Beta by the way

Comment: There is not Windows RT version of SharpDevelop at all. Even Microsoft does not support desktop apps in RT.

Comment: @LexLi I have jailbroken my RT machine. It may not be supported by Microsoft, but it's there. I just need help fixing the errors. I have .NET v4.0.30319 installed. The errors aren't CPU-type specific. As you can see here: https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/sharpdevelop-rt-edition-beta-code-windows-forms-directly-on-windows-rt/ It works on RT.